# How do I embed a for tag inside a block tag Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a for tag in my base template that loops over certain variables, depending upon the child template.

Like so:

```
{% for element in element_list %}
```

I want to override the element variable from a child template. So, I tried something like this:

```
{% for {% block element %}{% endblock element %} in {% block element_list %}{% endblock element_list %} %}
```

while doing this in the child template:

```
{% block element %}client{% endblock element %}
{% block element_list %}client_list{% endblock element_list %}
```

This approach did not work.

Then, I tried something else: I embedded the entire for tag inside a block tag, like so:

```
{% block fortag %}{% endblock fortag %}
```

in the parent template

...and

```
{% block fortag %}{% for client in client_list %}{% endblock fortag %}
```

in the child template.

Unfortunately, this did not work either.

I have two child templates called client and index which need different variables in the for tag. I know I can just name the variables the same and it would probably work. But I want to know the best approach to solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using generic views, you can use the context_object_name attribute.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is way to go. I was trying to do something that should be done in the view in the template, I guess. Eventually, this is what I went with and it works fine. Thanks.